# how to paste text in MS Word from vb.net program with short keys

Tags: vb.net, text, ms-word, paste

I need to know how to paste text in MS Word from vb.net program with short keys. 
My goals:

1. making a simple vb.net form and enter text and short key combination by user. And store both in an access database table.
2. In Microsoft Word or any other word processor, user can press the shortkey for the text which he already entered in vb.net program. And the same text sholud be displayed in word. How to do this. I only know to save the text in any database and retrieve it.

Please help me to find the rest.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most Windows controls, including VB.Net forms and Microsoft Word, let you copy text using the CTRL+C keyboard shortcut, and paste using the CTRL+V shortcut. This requires no additional programming.

Comment: When we ant to do the same task 1000 times ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Microsoft Word Interop namepsace. MS access has a similar namespace.

Go to the project dropdown menu and select 'Add reference' then under the 'Com' tab select the access and word interop assemblies.

Paste this to the top of your code:

```
 Import microsoft.office.interop.word
 Import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access
```

Here is the list of classes and a good help guide.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43746-Word-Automation-using-VB-NET.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx

As far as the hotkeys, pick an event such as a button click and use a conditional statement such as

```
 If Keys.shift + Keys.A Then
   Statements here   
End If
```